# Meteor, MongoDB and Manual References

Tags: mongodb, meteor, normalization

I'm building sort of a question and answer system for my Meteor project. I have 3 collections: one named "Questions," one named "Answers," and one for admins to manually determine a *question of the day,* named "Today."

All collected answers will reference the question of the day. What I'm trying to figure out is how to make an **insert statement** for the "Answers" collection. Among the fields, it should add the ObjectId of the question being stored in "Today."

```
Answers.insert({
  user: Meteor.userId(), 
  date: new Date(),
  answer: answer,
  questions_id: **here is where I would like the ObjectId of the current question**
})
```

How can I reference and insert an `ObjectId` value, belonging to a field (let's call the field QOD) within the `Today` collection? If you have an answer with an actual example, it would be great. I'm not so experienced that someone can describe a solution to me without showing it. Thanks.

Of course, I'll also have to figure out how to publish this stuff later. But I'll cross that road when I get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Answers` needs to reference a record from `Questions`, then you need to obtain that record and include the `_id` field in the object you'll insert in `Answers`:

```
var question = Questions.findOne({...criteria...});
Answers.insert({
  user: Meteor.userId(),
  date: new Date(),
  answer: answer,
  questionId: question._id
});
```

Hope this helps. I see "Entries" instead of "Answers" in your question though so you may want to clarify. Also, instead of a separate "Today" collection, you may want to have a separate field in the Questions collection which would mark certain questions as being selected as "Question of the Day".

Comment: Thanks. I left "Entries" there by accident. It should be Answers.

Comment: Wait ... I think I got it. Thanks a million.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can edit your own question and update `Entries` to `Answers`. As for what goes in the "criteria", that's a Mongo selector - see the [meteor docs for `find()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#find). To retrieve a single value, pass a `fields` key to `find`, then from the object returned by `findOne`, fetch the field you want (`_id` in my example above).  [This post on Meteor collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826804/understanding-meteor-publish-subscribe/21853298#21853298) might help understand more about collections in general.

Comment: Ha, I figured criteria out and tried to edit that question really fast, but I guess you started answering quickly. It works perfectly. I can't upvote with my rep yet, but it's definitely accepted.

Comment: It looks like "questionId = question._id" should be "questionId: question._id."