# display values from a form to only current user in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I have a form which collects some information from logged in user. I am able to store collected data in a collection and display it to user. I want to show a preview of collected data and ask him for confirmation before that gets published to all other clients or users.

please suggest the way to do so.I saw the Meteor.pulish() in docs but not able understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor.publish does something different, and works on server-side. Please [read this to understand how to use Meteor.publish, collections and subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826804/understanding-meteor-publish-subscribe/21853298#21853298).

What you want to do needs to be done client-side, with the values from the form, before you insert them in the collection; that's because once you do the *collection*.`insert`, meteor will send the record to the server, which will publish it to all other clients.

Comment: Can u pls help me out how can I handle the collection before inserting in the db.