# Meteor reactive publish based on client session variable

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm making a meteor js web app that presents the client an html range slider tied to a session variable.

I want the server to only publish data with values less than the current value of the slider with data sorted from newest to oldest. I have a lot of database entries (2000+). If I publish everything within the max of slider my browsers too slow. If I limit the publish to 100 entries or so, I miss out on a lot of data with small values (which happen to be older) when I bring the slider down.

What are the best practices for trying to be scalable (not sending too much data to the client)? Is a reactive publish function the key (using onchange with the slider value as the key)? That sounds like a lot of server round trips. Help!

Comment: Regarding your question about reactive subscribing based on a client session variable: it's definitely possible. Here's an example for your particular case:

Deps.autorun(function () {
   Meteor.subscribe("yourCL", selectorArgs, Number(Session.get('yourSessVar')));
});

The meteor documentation seems to show a new method called "Tracker.autorun"; however I haven't used it. It claims to skip a wasteful unsubscribe/resubscribe

Comment: I understand the subscribe part of it. My publish function seems to rerun every time that session variable changes (I log the variable via the server). My publish just doesn't send a new subset of the database when I want to...

Comment: Without code, it's hard to take a guess. Would a read over [how publish/subscribe works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826804/understanding-meteor-publish-subscribe) help?

Answer (score 1):

Would pagination be acceptable from a UX standpoint? If so, there are packages that may help, for instance [alethes:pages](https://atmospherejs.com/alethes/pages).

Otherwise, [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534113/meteor-reactive-publish-based-on-client-session-variable#comment41695606_26534113) is on the right track by suggesting to use [Tracker.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#tracker) (`Tracker` has replaced `Deps`).

As with any other publication, make sure your publish function [only returns the fields that you need on the client](http://docs.meteor.com/#fieldspecifiers), in order to minimize the data transferred and the memory consumption.

Comment: I want to publish more entries to the client if the user chooses to see more. I'd rather not initially flood the client with everything. I'm not sure if I necessarily need pages to do that.