# Mongo Insert Inside of a Meteor Method?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

In my Meteor app, I have a Meteor method that takes the collection as a parameter and tries to run the mongo `insert` command on that collection to create a new document. The code runs every 10 seconds using `setInterval`.

Collection is defined:

```
My_Collection_Name = new Meteor.Collection('my_collection_name');
```

---

Server code:

```
var collection = My_Collection_Name;
var data = [1,2,3,'a','b','c'];
Meteor.call('createDocument', collection, data);
```

---

Method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  createDocument: function(collection, data) {
    collection.insert({
      data: data
    });
  }
});
```

---

However, this returns the following error in the console:

```
I20141030-14:58:06.716(-4)? Exception in setInterval callback: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'insert'
```

Why doesn't this work? Is it possible to pass in the collection as a parameter? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is that you have *different* collections on the client and on the server (read more at [Understanding Meteor publish/subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826804/understanding-meteor-publish-subscribe)). Relying on the ~private `_collection` field is risky. What you do want is to indeed pass the collection name as a string to Meteor.call, make sure you have the same variable name on the server for the collection, and look up the collection by its name in the `global` object on the server:

```
// on the client:

MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection('record-set-name');  // set server-side by .publish()
Meteor.call('createDocument', 'MyCollection', data);

// on the server:
MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection('collection-name-in-mongo');
Meteor.methods({
  createDocument: function(collectionName, data) {
    global[collectionName].insert({
      data: data
    });
  }
});
```

This pattern is used by meteor-autocomplete to [pass collection names from the client to the server](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete/blob/master/autocomplete-server.coffee#L8).

[Understanding Meteor publish/subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826804/understanding-meteor-publish-subscribe) explains how the collection name and collection variable name relate in Mongo.

Comment: Wonderful answer, efficient and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Dan!

Answer (score 0):

After further inspection of the collection object, I noticed that it has a `_collection` object inside which, in turn, contains the `insert`, `update`, etc. functions. Therefore, adjusting the code to the below solves the problem for running Mongo commands against a collection parameter inside a Meteor method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  createDocument: function(collection, data) {
    collection._collection.insert({
      data: data
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This needlessly passes and entire object to the server, and assumes the collections are named the same on the client as the publications are on the server. Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26664357/1269037) for the correct solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think here `collection` variable is taking as a collection name, If you have few collection names you can do it like below in the server methods

```
Meteor.methods({
  createDocument: function(collection, data) {
    if(collection == "firstcollection")
    {
      firstcollection.insert({
        data: data
      });
   }
   else if(collection == "secondcollection")
    {
      secondcollection.insert({
        data: data
      });
   }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, my collection variable is not a string, it's an object. So I can't string-check like that, nor do I think it would work trying to insert on a string.