# Meteor publication and subscribe understand

Tags: meteor

I have publish code on server-side:

```
Meteor.publish("getChannelsList", function() {
   return News.find({ }, { title: 1 });
});
```

And subscriptions.js on client:

```
Meteor.subscribe("getChannelsList", function(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    throw new Meteor.Error("Subscription error", "Exception in Meteor.subscribe method", err);
  }
  return res;
});
```

Collection in it's own "collections" directory

```
News = new Meteor.Collection("newsStock");
```

This is my template helper:

```
Template.channel.helpers({
    channels: function() {
        return News.find({ }, { title: 1 });
    }
});
```

Autopublish and insecure were removed.
I'm waiting on client database object with "title" and "id" only. If I do in browser debugger News.find().pretty() why I see whole object, with all fields? Removing autopublish is not affect for me.

Can I do multiple publications and subscribes and how it's works?

Comment: I wrote a well-received post about multiple publications at [Understanding Meteor Publish/Subscribe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826804/understanding-meteor-publish-subscribe/21853298#21853298). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only intending to return the title, it should be:

```
Template.channel.helpers({
    channels: function() {
        return News.find({ }, {
            fields: {
                title: 1 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

As you point out, this will also publish the `_id` by default.

Comment: Yes, this work for me. Thank you. With my small experience in Mongo and Meteor can I ask one more question? Why if I execute in Mongo shell db.newsStock.find({}, {fields: {title: 1}}).pretty() Mongo throw error, but db.newsStock.find({}, {title: 1}).pretty() work well. Meteor Mongo and Mongo not equal?

Comment: Correct, the APIs are not equivalent, particularly when it comes to sorting, skipping and limiting.  Meteor find API is [well-documented](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find), and I would always refer to the docs rather than relying on Mongo experience.