# Session variable based subscriptions and joins

Tags: meteor

I am wanting to display waypoints on a Google Maps API driven map which have not already been visited by a specific person.

I have two collections in MongoDB currently.

- waypoint:  consists of location and a guid (among other things)
- visit: consists of a player's guid and a waypoint guid

What I want is:

- The waypoints sent to the client are only the ones which can appear on the current map's bounds.
- If the map is moved (the bounds change), new waypoints will appear as needed.  Ideally the old ones would be removed from the client as they fall out of view as well.
- If a new waypoint is added, it would be added to the map for the person.
- If that player then visits that waypoint, adding the associated record to the visits database would cause the waypoint to disappear from the map.
- If the waypoint is deleted or updated, it is removed or updated on the map as well.

I'm still very new to Meteor, and while I think I understand a single subscription (or even multiple subscriptions for the same collection) well, I am having trouble coming up with a reactive solution that doesn't involve pouring a lot of data into the browser.

I'm having problems figuring out how to combine this into something simple.  I fear there is no way, but links to options would help.

Answer (score 0):

When you describe sounds doable. Have a look at [understanding Meteor publish/subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826804/understanding-meteor-publish-subscribe/21853298#21853298) first then revisit the problem.

The way I'd structure the publication would be like this:

```js
// server - takes care of requirements 1, 3 and 5
Meteor.publish('waypoints-within-bounds', function publishFunction(bounds) {
  return Waypoints.find({
    location: {
      $geoWithin: {
        $box: [ bounds.bottomLeft, bounds.upperRight ]
      }
    },
    guid: {
      $nin:  // array of visited waypoint guids; Mongo doesn't have joins
    }
  });
});


// client - this takes care of requirement #2
Tracker.autorun(function () {
  Meteor.subscribe('waypoints-within-bounds', Session.get('mapBounds'));
});

function updateMapBounds() {
  var bounds = map.mapObject.getBounds();
  // massage developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds
  // to match MongoDB's $box parameter order: [...]
  Session.set('mapBounds', bounds);
}

google.maps.event.addListener(map.mapObject, 'center_changed', updateMapBounds);
google.maps.event.addListener(map.mapObject, 'zoom_changed', updateMapBounds);
```

The above are raw calls to the Google Maps API, but you'll probably want to use [dburles:google-maps](https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/google-maps).

Now we need to take care of the last requirement: "If that player then visits that waypoint, adding the associated record to the visits database would cause the waypoint to disappear from the map." That's best done with a [Meteor.method](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-methods) which you'll call from the client when a waypoint is visited.

Going forward, you might want to have [template-level subscriptions](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/) instead, and [keep an eye on this feature making it into Meteor core](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/3559).