# Is that secure to compare mongodb dates on client-side?

Tags: mongodb, date, meteor

I have a publication where I send a "record set" of items. Among these items, some have a field with a modification date (Type: Date).

I need to compare the date field with the current date in order to allow/forbid a user interface action. If my date is more than 24hours ago, the action is forbidden.

Initially, I wanted to create a dedicated publication in order to expose only the _id of the items with a Date field inferior to 24h from now.

When reading the excellent answer from @Dan Dascalescu [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826804/understanding-meteor-publish-subscribe/21853298#21853298), I understood that I can't have different minimongo collections if the original Mongodb collection is the same: even if I use different subscriptions everything end up in the same minimongo collection/"record set".

I could just read and compare the Date field on client side and allow/forbid the action but is that secure? Can the client change the date manually? What would be the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Is _[insert some action on some client]_ secure? No. Never. Server-side validation or your app is standing on top of a cliff, with a noose around the neck, sharp rocks and hungry sharks in the lava pit below it... and your client is behind it, waiting to push.

Comment: I wasn't picturing it exactly like that but I had a similar idea on this :-) My main issue is then how to do this server-side in Meteor? Ideally, I would like to create a boolean field "older than 24h" from my Date field and add it to my subscription, server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any checks that you do to forbid an action have a security implication. There are approaches that you can use here:

1. use [Methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-methods) server side along with [Meteor.call](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call) client side.
2. use [deny](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/deny) rules if it's collection related. That way you get isomorphic behavior for free and instant feedback on client without sacrificing security.

Comment: I'll validate this answer. To achieve that, I will try a server Method. I struggle with it since yesterday but I guess it is another topic. Thanks!