# Meteor.loginWithPassword callback doesn't provide custom object in User accounts doc

Tags: authentication, meteor

Meteors loginWithPassword() function doesn't provide me the object systemData, which I adding to user doc (not to profile obj) during registration. The thing is, that if I look into console after logging in, I *can* see that object systemData (that means probably it's not publish issue), but not in callback of loginWithPassword() function, where I need them (to dynamically redirect user to proper page). Is there way to get this object, without any ugly things like timers?

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(errorObject) {
if (errorObject) {
 ...
} else {

// returns true
if (Meteor.userId()) {
    // returns false
    if (Meteor.user().systemData) {
    ...
    }
    // user doc without systemData object
    console.log(JSON.stringify(Meteor.user());
}

}
```

I've adding object systemData on creating user:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {

if (options.profile) {
user.profile = options.profile;
}
...
user.systemData = systemDataRegularUser;
return user;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure publish data to Client ?

I get User Info  Using loginWithPassword in callback function.

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword username,password,(error,result1)->
                  options =             
                      username: username
                      password: password
                      email: result['data']['email']
                      profile:          
                          name: result['data']['display-name']
                          roles: result.roles
                  console.log Meteor.user(), result1
```

I Create user flowing code: (options contains systemData)

```
Accounts.createUser option
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you want a custom field on a user document published to the client. This is a common question - see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151879/publish-certain-information-for-meteor-users-and-more-information-for-meteor-use).

The next problem is that even after you add something like:

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {fields: {systemData: 1}});
});
```

I think you still have a race condition. When you call `loginWithPassword`, the server will publish your user document, but it will also publish another version of the same document with the `systemData` field. You are hoping that both events have completed by the time `Meteor.user()` is called. In practice this may just work, but I'm not sure there is any guarantee that it always will. As you suggested, if you added a slight delay with a timer that would probably work but it's an ugly hack.

Alternatively, can you just add `systemData` to the user's `profile` so it will always be published?

Comment: Why I haven't my secret object systemData in profile object I've described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/21345829/1709785. There was probably some interference with publish function in Meteor Account package: `Meteor.publish(null, function() { });` where is hardcoded `{profile: 1, username: 1, emails: 1}`. I've tried to extend that in my app, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find exact way how to solve this, but found easy workaround.
To make some action right after user logged in (eg. dynamically redirect user to proper page), you can hook on your home page with Iron router.(If you using it.) :

```
this.route('UsersListingHome', {
  path: '/',
  template: 'UsersListing',
  data: function() { ... },
  before: function() {    
    if (isCurrentUserAdmin() && Session.get('adminJustLogged') !== 'loggedIn') {
      Router.go('/page-to-redirect');
      Session.set('adminJustLogged','loggedIn');    
    }
  }
});
```

After click on logout of course `if (isCurrentUserAdmin()) { Session.set('adminJustLogged', null); }`

I've further thought about calling `Meteor.call('someMethod')` to fetch userData object in Method callback, but now I'm satisfied.

PS: I know that it's not recommended to have plenty session variables or other reactive data source for speeding-up my app, but I believe, that one is not tragedy :)
PS2: Anyway, thanks for your answers.