# How do I find an element in meteor.users then insert/update/upsert my data an empty array, then update if I found it? In mongodb and meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How do I find course_id in meteor.users then insert/update/upsert my data into "classes" (an empty array)?

if cant find course_id then insert a new array, if i can then i update the array with new classes_id.

Empty classes array:

```
{
  "_id": "RoFFcaAfXBeR2napZ",
  "emails": [
    {
      "address": "tong@gmail.com",
      "verified": false
    }
  ],
  "classes": [],
  "courses": [
    "qwmZdgQbrZ3rmHdN8"
  ]
}
```

Insert new array to classes if i cant find course_id:

```
{
  "_id": "RoFFcaAfXBeR2napZ",
  "emails": [
    {
      "address": "tong@gmail.com",
      "verified": false
    }
  ],
  "classes": [
      {
         "course_id": "svesvinfdsgrvnekuktndvsk",
         "classes_id": ["myclass1"]
      },
  ],
  "courses": [
    "qwmZdgQbrZ3rmHdN8"
  ]
}
```

Add myclass2 to classes_id if i can find course_id

```
{
  "_id": "RoFFcaAfXBeR2napZ",
  "emails": [
    {
      "address": "tong@gmail.com",
      "verified": false
    }
  ],
  "classes": [
      {
         "course_id": "svesvinfdsgrvnekuktndvsk",
         "classes_id": ["myclass1", "myclass2"]
      },
  ],
  "courses": [
    "qwmZdgQbrZ3rmHdN8"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the record that has the course ID in question: `Meteor.users.find({"courses": yourVariableHoldingTheId})` is an example query. This assumes that your publication has the courses field on it (more on publishing Users [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151879/publish-certain-information-for-meteor-users-and-more-information-for-meteor-use) and [Meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_user).

From that query, you'll now have the [Cursor](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-find) of Users that meet your criteria. Iterate over the users and treat them as normal JS objects - check your criteria and either push to the classes subdocument, or push to the classes.$.classesId.

Pushing to classes `Meteor.users.update({_id: "RoFFcaAfXBeR2napZ"}, {$push: {'classes': {'course_id': 'yourGibberishHere', 'classes_id': ['test']}}});`

Pushing to the classes_id `Meteor.users.update({"classes.course_id": "svesvinfdsgrvnekuktndvsk"}, {$push: {"classes.$.classes_id": "myclass3"}});` *tested on Mongo 3.2, your mileage may vary in meteor (2.6 or 3.2, if you're using external mongo). Older commentary points to x.$.y not working in meteor/mongo $push, not sure if this is still the case.*

If any of these fail, you can manipulate the object returned from the find and update it or subdocuments thereof using more accessible calls

Comment: how do I check if the course_id exist? if exist push, if not exist create the course_id?

Comment: I think i just findone, if nth then create course_id. dont know if that is the best way

Comment: I suspect I may have address the incorrect course_id in my initial answer; please let me know if that's the case.
To address checking for the course_id, (classes.$.course_id), you should be able to find as so 

`Meteor.users.find({"classes.course_id": "svesvinfdsgrvnekuktndvsk"});`
or `Meteor.users.findOne({"classes.course_id": "svesvinfdsgrvnekuktndvsk"});`