# Show All Users in Meteor React Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

I am having some trouble getting all the registered users to display on the client side. `std:accounts-ui` package is included in `.meteor/packages`. `autopublish` package has been removed.

The data for all users are published in `Users.js` as `allUsers`, while the client subscribes to the `allUsers` publication from within `createContainer` provided by `react-meteor-data`.

However the page only renders the details of the user that is currently logged in. Running `Meteor.users().find().fetch()` in the browser JS console only shows the currently logged in user, and shows nothing if the user is not logged in.

Running `console.log(Meteor.users.find().fetch()` on the server side outputs all the users correctly.

Why is this happening on the browser?

**/imports/api/Users.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('allUsers', function() {
        return Meteor.users.find({});
    })
}
```

**/imports/ui/App.jsx**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/std:accounts-ui';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import User from './User';


export class App extends Component {

    renderUsers() {
        return this.props.users.map((user) => (
            <User key={user._id} user={user} />
        ));
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Users</h1>

                <Table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td>Email</td>
                            <td>createdAt</td>
                        </tr>

                        { this.renderUsers() }

                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

App.propTypes = {
    users: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default createContainer(() => {
    Meteor.subscribe('allUsers');

    return {
        users: Meteor.users.find().fetch()
    }
}, App);
```

**/imports/ui/User.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Users extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{ this.props.user._id}</td>
                <td>{ _.get(this.props, 'user.emails[0].address', 'UNKNOWN') }</td>
                <td>{ this.props.user.createdAt }</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvote for using plural "are" for data.

Comment: @JonathanWheeler omg thank you!!! :)

Comment: Meteor.user() I know is a built in function. Can you still access your function that you describe here if you do not subscribe to allUsers?

Comment: @JonathanWheeler Yes it can still be accessed in the browser JS console if not subscribed

Comment: That may be the problem. You might be trying to overload a built in function. This has been a pain in the neck for me whenever I build Meteor apps

Comment: @JonathanWheeler I followed the [solution to this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151879/publish-certain-information-for-meteor-users-and-more-information-for-meteor-use). It publishes `Meteor.users.find()` and subscribes to this.

Comment: That's about all the help I can give them. I always got stuck at things like this myself.

Comment: Strange. Your code looks exactly correct. What happens if you open up the console of your browser and type `Meteor.subscribe('allUsers')` followed by `Meteor.users.find().fetch()`? What do you see?

Comment: @ffxsam From the console output of `Meteor.users.find().fetch()`, I still see only the currently logged in user...

Comment: Strange. What if you put a `console.log` statement inside your publish function? Is the publish function actually getting called?

Comment: PS: I would take the answer below with a grain of salt. I think there's something else wrong going on in your code, because you absolutely should be able to publish all users. I'm doing this in two projects of mine.

Comment: @ffxsam Yes the publish function is being called, added `console.log` into the callback function of `Meteor.publish`....

Comment: @ffxsam, just solved the problem. I had `import User from './User';` but was exporting `Users` instead of `User`. That somehow messed up the publication subscription. Finally solved!!

Comment: @Nyxynyx Glad to hear! :)

Comment: @Nyxynyx Glad to hear you have solved your problem :). I think my answer works only for angular2-meteor. React may have different way of publishing. i have checked it on 14.4 Create Users collection from Meteor.users of https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/using-and-creating-angularjs-pipes  angular2-meteor  official tutorial.You can check. For angular you actually have to create a collection. I though it would work for React also. Anyway i was just trying to help

Comment: @AmitSuhag Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

i have faced the same problem when i was using angular 2 and meteor. i also tried to accesss data using `Meteor.users.find({});`

but this is not the correct way to use.
for using this first you should create a new collection like this

```
export const Users = MongoObservable.fromExisting(Meteor.users);<-- most important line
```

then in

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function() {
        if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'admin')) {
            return Meteor.users.find();
        } else {
            const selector = {
                '_id': this.userId
            };
            return Meteor.users.find(selector);
        }
    });
```

and use in your file by subscribe to it.

```
MeteorObservable.subscribe('userData').subscribe(() => { 
                     this.userlist=Users.find({});      
            });
```

i did it in angular 2.you plz use react syntax for last subscribe part.

Comment: I tried `import { Meteor, MongoObservable } from 'meteor/meteor';` and `const Users = MongoObservable.fromExisting(Meteor.users);` but got the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromExisting' of undefined` in the browser console.

Comment: Do I need to install any packages to access `MongoObservable`? Such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-rxjs or is it now built into Meteor?

Comment: you don't have to use MongoObservable. In react meteor there should be a method for creating a collection from existing. first try using export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection(Meteor.users); I never used react so can't tell you exactly but there should be some way.

Comment: @Nyxynyx actually meteor automatically create a users collection for Meteor.users if you have seen you mongodb. you just have to use that collection. for that either you create a new collection  which will be copy of you default users collection using  new Mongo.Collection(Meteor.users); or you can directly subscribe to you monogdb users collection.