# Meteor JS - Collections (mongodb) can be changed by any visitor (Not secure)

Tags: javascript, database, meteor

I am using the Meteor JS node framework for a project I am working on.

I noticed that anyone visiting my website can simply enter a similar command into the javascript console in their browser and edit my database.

```
MyCollection.insert({name: 'I am a hacker', message: 'hahaha'});
```

Is there any way to stop users from being able to do this?

This is really not secure, all they need to do is find the name of the Collection and they can do anything they want.

How can I fix this problem?

Should I use a different framework, is Meteor JS not ideal for a large-scale project?

Thanks,

Jonathan.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115042/how-do-you-secure-the-client-side-mongodb-api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would do best to read their docs, specifically http://docs.meteor.com/#dataandsecurity

Comment: Oh, so I will need to remove the autopublish and insecure packages? Thank you!

Comment: You can also see the [parties example screencast](http://meteor.com/examples/parties) for better understanding.