# Error updating miniMongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Originally, I have a nested object like so:
    db.insert{a:1, b:2, c:{}}
and I would like to insert content into object c. So I use the following:
    db.update({a:1}, {$set: {c: {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}}})

However, I keep get error messages. How do I make an insert for the nested object?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I'm using Meteor and all I see Meteor.Error.prototype = new Error; I also tried the dot syntax in db.update({a:1}, {$set: {'c.one': 1}}); In addition, I wonder what if I need multiple items in the c object? Create an array?

Comment: Are you using `meteor mongo` for these commands or using them directly in your application?

Comment: @Prashant I've tried command line and script execution. Have not tried meteor mongo yet

Answer (score 0):

In Meteor, you need to initialize the MongoDB collection in a global scope like so,

`YourCollection = new Meteor.Collection("yourcollection")`

Remember this needs to be in global scope, which means you need to add this out of the client or server code, so that both can access this collection.

Then you can do,

`YourCollection.insert({ a: 1, b: 2 })`

You need not add a field `c` if it does not contain any object. This is the power of MongoDB.

As of 0.5.8, Meteor does not allow you to update documents from client using arbitrary Mongo selectors. To know more about this read [Understanding “Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID.” Meteor error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464507/understanding-not-permitted-untrusted-code-may-only-update-documents-by-id-m/15465286#15465286). So you can alternatively use `Meteor.methods`.

But if you'd like to update from client, you can still do,

`YourCollection.update( { _id: "tdMrJojHyxWQ8tr6w" }, { $set : { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 } } )`