# renaming many fields in mongodb/meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm attempting to update many field titles in my meteor database (mongodb) and I'm struggling with syntax. Here is an example of one entry in my collection called 'Lessons':

```
{
"_id": "R6AnePqKecNNe7dkr",
"title": "A Title Name",
"categoryA": "Category Name"
}
```

I'm trying to update every file within the 'Lessons' collection to replace 'categoryA' with 'category0' and this is the code I'm running based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254351/how-can-i-rename-a-field-for-all-documents-in-mongodb):

```
Lessons.update({}, {$rename:{"categoryA":"category0"}}, { upsert:false, multi:true });
```

I tried running it within the client shell but it came up with an error "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID." which I attribute to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464507/understanding-not-permitted-untrusted-code-may-only-update-documents-by-id-m).

Then I tried running it within the server shell but it said 'Lessons.update' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Then I made a button within my site and when clicked it would run that code in a method on the server side. There are no errors or warnings when the button is pressed but the database remains unchanged.

I've also tried using 'updateMany' instead of 'update' but that just just comes up with an 'internal server error [500]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to run the mongo shell on the server

```
meteor mongo
```

then select the meteor database

```
use meteor
```

then use the following syntax

```
db.lessons.update({},{$rename:{"categoryA":"category0"}}, {multi:true})
```