# How do I update a collection using multiple _id's?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I am trying to update a collection based on multiple **_id**'s.

I recieve the **_id**'s in an array format via a **Session.get()** as below:

```
 var selectedID = Session.get('selectedItemIDSet');

 console.log("selectedID array contents are: "+selectedID);
```

The code above ensures that the `selectedID` array exists and yields:

**selectedID array contents are: LZJKA8S3wYNwHakzE,ikrbCDuttHrwkEcuv**

The Query below:

```
buyList.find({_id:{ "$in": selectedID} }).fetch();
```

Successfully yeilds two Objects!

Now to area am having issues with, how to I update the collection with these two **_id**'s

I have tried with the below code:

```
var PostedArray = [{PostedBy: Meteor.user()._id }];
buyList.update(_id: selectedID, {$set: {wishListArray: PostedArray} });
```

...but get error message: **Uncaught Error: Mongo selector can't be an array.(…)**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same selector in your [`update`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-update) as you have done for your `find` + specify the `multi: true` option:

```js
buyList.update({ // selector
  _id: {
    "$in": selectedID
  }
}, { // modifier
  $set: {
    wishListArray: PostedArray
  }
}, { // options
  multi: true
});
```

Note that your 2 documents will be updated with the same modifier.

Comment: You'll also want to add ```{multi: true}``` to the end to make sure more than 1 document is updated. So the final code would be ```buyList.update({ _id: { "$in": selectedID }}, { $set: { wishListArray: PostedArray }}, { multi: true });```

Comment: @ghybs Thanks guys. Following your advice, am getting this error message: Uncaught. errorClass {error: 403, reason: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID." , details: undefined, message: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}

Comment: @SirBT Where are you executing your code? Do you still have `insecure` package?

Comment: @ghybs I am executing the code on the chrome browser console, which am assuming is equivalent to running it on the client side.  No, I don't have insecure package. I removed that a while ago.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464507/understanding-not-permitted-untrusted-code-may-only-update-documents-by-id-m

Comment: @ghybs thanks! Once I moved it to the server side, it worked. Thanks a bunch!