# Validate login credentials without signing in?

Tags: authentication, meteor

I am working on a 2FA implementation in meteor and have been able to send and validate codes via SMS.

However, I would like to validate user credentials (username, pass) without logging them in. The logic for this being that I would like a login process that goes: user enters credentials -> send text code -> validate text code -> login user.

Any help / advice would be appreciated!

Comment: See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214496/verify-user-password-in-meteor) - let me know if you think this is a duplicate.

Comment: Does `Accounts._checkPassword(user, password)` do it for you (on the server)?